# i get this every time i open vs code: The Flutter Daemon failed to start

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i get this every time i open vs code The Flutter Daemon failed to start and i cant select any device
my flutter doctor results:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
 Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Versiyon 10.0.22621.1848], locale tr-TR)
 Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
 Chrome - develop for the web
 Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.7.0 Preview 2.0)
 Android Studio (version 2022.2)
 VS Code (version 1.79.2)
 Connected device (3 available)
Network resources

• No issues found!
```

I tried a few things, I even installed the dart sdk but I couldn't run it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to upgrade flutter :

```
flutter upgrade
```

Then Try:

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get 
flutter run
```

Restart also Vs code.

Comment: are you getting this stuff from chatgpt or another AI? I've noticed you're posting a lot of answers that the askers are saying don't work. If you are, which AI are you using? can you explain how you're coming to these answers that you're writing?

Comment: make sense that you think like this, if you pay close attention to my profile i replied to 4 questions. 1 one question i solved the issue but the owner of the question copy pasted my solution and writed an answer to his own question with my solution, other 3 questions was missing complete code and unable to debug at all. I this case i don't think that you need Ai to answer to this basic question if you have some expereince in Flutter

Comment: @starball I'm a Flutter Certified Application Developer, and i work with flutter from 4+ years, i'm also active in the italian Flutter community and i have conncetion with many Flutter GDE. Before judging you may want to look that i'm still contributing in my spare time to help others, in your case you are simply commenting without clue.

Comment: "_other 3 questions was missing complete code and unable to debug at all_" those kinds of questions are discouraged from being answered. see [answer].

Comment: dude instead of spamming with your comments, write a solution

Comment: @starball are you the guy how gave me -1 to my other replies ? ridiculous...